# Adding elements to an array through a function call

Tags: c

Can someone explain to me why this code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set_array(int array[3]);

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    set_array(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

void set_array(int array[3])
{
    array[3] = 4;
}
```

How is it possible that I can add an element to an array through a function call? Can someone explain to me what's happening behind the curtains here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why?

Comment: I have found that this compiles just fine and actually adds an element to the `a` array. Try it for yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need to allocate the array using `malloc()` and then use `realloc()`.